# Maven build is not getting scheduled on Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I am using Jenkins version 1.554.2. I have various maven project jobs. I have recently created a new maven job on Jenkins. It ran once on Jenkins. Now when I click on **Build Now**, It only shows tool tip `Build Scheduled` but does not schedule the build. My other maven project are running perfectly.

**Maven version**:3.2.1 Java version:1.7.0_55

**Job type** : maven2/3 project

**Installed plugins**:

```
 Install   
Build Blocker Plugin
Cobertura Plugin
Coverity plugin
Cppcheck Plug-in
Credentials Plugin
CVS Plug-in
Dashboard View
dbCharts
Duplicate Code Scanner Plug-in
Email Extension Plugin
Environment File Plugin
Environment Injector Plugin
External Monitor Job Type Plugin
Files Found Trigger
FindBugs Plug-in    
Green Balls
HTML Publisher plugin
Hudson Build-Publisher plugin
Hudson Personal View
Javadoc Plugin
Join plugin
LDAP Email Plugin
LDAP Plugin
Mailer Plugin
MapDB API Plugin
Maven Dependency Update Trigger
Maven Integration plugin
Nested View Plugin
OWASP Markup Formatter Plugin
Plot plugin
PMD Plug-in
promoted builds plugin
Radiator View Plugin
Sectioned View Plugin
Security Realm by custom script
Sidebar Link
SLOCCount Plug-in
SSH Credentials Plugin
SSH Slaves plugin
Static Analysis Collector Plug-in
Static Analysis Utilities
Subversion Plug-in
Task Scanner Plug-in
TextFinder plugin
Translation Assistance plugin
Valgrind Plug-in
ViewVC Plugin
Warnings Plug-in
Windows Slaves Plugin
```

Comment: First of all: Update your Jenkins, as this Version is very old... a recent version would be > 1.61x

Comment: I can not update my Jenkins.

Comment: why? ask your adminstrator to do so?

Comment: Yes,That can be done later.

Comment: Have a look at https://jenkins-ci.org/changelog to see, hooooow many bugs in jenkins itself have been fixed since version 1.554.2? It is hard to reproduce your described behaviour with such a historic version of that build-server as nearly nowbody runs that version - I hope you understand my point on that?

Comment: Yes, I have got your point.

Comment: Now, with so less information you gave us: how should we provide help on your problem? It is hard if we don't know the Jenkins properites/settings of this particular environment: Maven version(s)? Java version(s)? Job Type? Installed jenkins plugins? Plugins used for this job? What are other characteristics like SCM or Encoding of your underlying OS? What OS Jenkins runs on? Pls, provide all that information, else it will be nearly impossible to see the picture of your problem in that case.

Comment: Added some information in question. I think I should first upgrade the Jenkins.

Comment: Is the job configured to run on a particular node and is that node / agent active

Answer (score 0):

When this has happened to me it was because all my nodes were configured to allow only jobs that were restricted to a label that was associated with that node. When I created new jobs and forgot to restrict them to run only on nodes with a label, then they would never leave the build queue.

Use the job's "Restrict where this job can be run" parameter to configure which nodes (or node labels) the job can run on.
Use the node's "Leave this machine for tied jobs only" usage parameter to configure which jobs can run on this node.